# Display empty JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

We are having a `JScrollpane` with a `JPanel` with buttons in it.

At the beginning there will be no buttons to display.

Our GUI would always be destroyed then. How can we fix this?

We want the empty `JScrollPane` to be displayed.

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 500));
buttonPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(450, 500));
buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
pane.setSize(new Dimension(450, 500));
pane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(450, 500));

// GridBagConstraint for button
GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
constraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
constraint.gridx = 0;
constraint.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
constraint.weightx = 1.0f;
constraint.weighty = 1.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < countVeranstaltungen; i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(events[i].getTitel() + " " + events[i].getTreffpunkt() + " " + events[i].getTermin());
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 100));
    buttonPanel.add(button, constraint);

    Veranstaltungsdetails details = new Veranstaltungsdetails(events[i]);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            details.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

pane.setViewportView(buttonPanel);
this.jPanel3.add(pane);
pane.updateUI();
```

Comment: If it's empty, then there should be no need to display it. Please post a picture of what you want it to be displayed when no buttons are created and a proper [mcve]

Comment: The ScrollPane isn't empty, buttonPanel is.  An empty JPanel can't be displayed.  You should have a default image to show when there are no buttons.

Comment: Thank you!! But the problem was only a missing bracket at the end of a catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to override `getPreferredSize` method of the `JPanel` containing the buttons which is hold by the `JScrollPane`. This way there is always something to be displayed.

If you want the `JScrollBar`s are always displayed, you need to create your `JScrollPane` using the [`JScrollPanel(Component, int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int)) constructor as shown in the code below.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class EmptyJScrollPane {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JButton addButtons;
    private int number = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new EmptyJScrollPane()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };

        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        scroll = new JScrollPane(pane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        addButtons = new JButton("Add more buttons");
        addButtons.addActionListener(e -> {
            pane.add(new JButton("Button " + number));
            number++;

            pane.revalidate();
            pane.repaint();
        });

        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.add(addButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

#### Aside note:

Note that the above code is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will be required from you on your next questions.

Here's a before and after adding buttons images when the above code is run:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you!! But the problem was only a missing bracket at the end of a catch block.